# SaveAs Fails / Process Not Removed

Tags: excel, powershell

I've found numerous articles on how to save Excel and safely close out the process, however the spreadsheet still doesn't save the Excel process remains.

Any thoughts on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

```
$file = "C:\temp\testexcel.xls"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $true
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open("$file")
$workbook.SaveAs("$file")

$workbook.Close($true)
$objExcel.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
Remove-Variable objExcel
```

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens when you set `$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $true`?

Comment: It's working now.  Stupid mistake on my part.  I had an Exit rather than Return on a function.  As such, the clean up statements were completely skipped.  The knowledge on the GC and file format was helpful for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the [file format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) when saving a workbook as a different file:

```
$workbook.SaveAs($file, -4143)
```

If you just want to save the file use `Save()`, not `SaveAs()`:

```
$workbook.Save()
```

Also, run the garbage collector after you released the COM object:

```
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
Remove-Variable objExcel
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  I applied the file format and the GC.  Additionally, for testing, I commented out the display alerts.  With visible active, the spreadsheet display and I can see the changes occur, however the script ends and the spreadsheet remains open.  Additionally, when closing the spreadsheet, I get the message about wanting to save changes.  After all this, the process still remains.  It is behaving like the script is completely skipping the save statement.